# How do you properly configure an event listener/handler for a CategoryFilter control?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I am trying to plot the following sample data using a LineChart with a CategoryFilter to filter on year.

Data table is defined as:

> aggData: [Date: date][Team: string][Score: number]

From the `aggData` table I dynamically calculate the default hAxis ticks as

```
    var hAxisTicks = [];
    var dateRange = aggData.getColumnRange(0);

    for (var date = dateRange.min; date <= dateRange.max; date = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1)) {
        hAxisTicks.push(date);
    }
```

The year picker and the line chart are configured as:

```
var yearPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
        containerId: 'categoryFilter_div',
        options: {
            filterColumnIndex: 0,
            ui: {
                allowTyping: false,
                allowMultiple: false,
                label: 'Year:',
                labelStacking: 'vertical'
            },
            useFormattedValue: true
        }
    });

var lineChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'LineChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div',
    options: {
        width: 900,
        height: 500,
        hAxis: {
           format: 'MMM', ticks: hAxisTicks
        }
    }
});
```

I added the following event listener

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(yearPicker, 'statechange', function () {

    google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(lineChart, 'ready', getTicks);
});
```

I need to create/recreate the hAxis ticks everytime the `yearPicker` changes by calling `getTicks`

```
function getTicks() {
        var ticks = [];
        if (yearPicker.getState().selectedValues.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i <= hAxisTicks.length; i = i + 1) {
                var date = new Date(hAxisTicks[i]);
                if (date.getFullYear() == yearPicker.getState().selectedValues[0]) {
                    ticks.push(date)
                }
            }
        }

        else {
            for (var i = 0; i <= hAxisTicks.length; i = i + 1) {
                var date = new Date(hAxisTicks[i]);
                ticks.push(date);
            }
            lineChart.setOption('hAxis.ticks', ticks);
            lineChart.draw();
        }
        lineChart.setOption('hAxis.ticks', ticks);
        lineChart.draw();
    }
```

Here's what happens at different stages

1- When page first loads the graph looks like (the `getTicks` function is NOT called) which is correct:
[image]

2- When the year is changed to 2019, for example, the hAxis ticks get recalculated (the `getTicks` function is does get called) and the graph appears to be correct
[image]

3- Attempting to go back to the default chart to display all years, an `a.getTime is not a function` error message appears under the CategoryFilter
[image]

4- Any subsequent attempts to change the CategoryFilter to any value throws a ```One or more participants failed to draw()
[image]

How can I rectify this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I realized my iteration over the hAxisTics array was incorrect. I should stop at `< hAxisTics.length` instead of `<= hAxisTics.length` and I should recalculate inside the event handler

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(yearPicker, 'statechange', function () {
    var ticks = [];
    if (yearPicker.getState().selectedValues.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < hAxisTicks.length; i = i + 1) {
            var date = new Date(hAxisTicks[i]);
            if (date.getFullYear() == yearPicker.getState().selectedValues[0]) {
                ticks.push(date)
            }
        }
    }

    else {
        for (var i = 0; i < hAxisTicks.length; i = i + 1) {
            var date = new Date(hAxisTicks[i]);
            ticks.push(date);
        }
        lineChart.setOption('hAxis.ticks', ticks);
        lineChart.draw();
    }
    lineChart.setOption('hAxis.ticks', ticks);
    lineChart.draw();
});
```